# How to describe framework/features of a java application for client presentation?

Tags: web-framework, presentation, product-features

I have been asked to put down the architecture and features of our Java application (more from infrastructure/software point of view). It will go on a Powerpoint presentation, so I need to provide the list.

Please let me know how do I go about this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Know Your Audience**

I would say that it depends on your client. If your client is a consumer/business using your software as a service, bear in mind that they care little about the technical aspects. If you were selling a POS ("Point of Sale" - something like a grocery checkout program) program, you might list features like so:

- Can process credit cards at lightspeed.
- Can scan users faces and bill them using the unique creases on their foreheads.
- Can convince customers to buy the candy at the counter on impulse

If you were selling this to a technical client, for say, integration with another product, you might consider discussing the technical aspects. For example (I'm not a Java programmer, so excuse any mistaken false promises, I'm being facetious):

- Can process a hundred threads in under thirty nanoseconds
- Can process credit cards across securely using the  algorithm.

**Know Your Subject**

Since you seem to be leaning towards the technical side, you might want to list the programming paradigms that you use and some of the highlights of the architecture of your program. If I were presenting one of my iPhone apps, for example, I'd almost surely mention the Model-View-Controller paradigm.
I may also mention the delegation patterns used. You may want to discuss particular modularization or inheritance patterns as well as frameworks that you use.

Remember, regardless of what goes in to the presentation: *if you don't know how your program works, you can't share that information with others.*

**Structure Your Presentation**

I'd start with a bulleted list and go through the bullets one by one. If you're having trouble with layout and such, use a template that comes with Powerpoint. If  you're looking for inspiration for structuring your presentation, take a look at any one of Apple's presentations. You can watch a keynote, or a technology demo. Those are done really well.

Comment: I think you hit this one on the nail the only thing That I would recommend is on non-techoncal viewers keep things simple not like they are dumb but try not to distact them and dont get carried into one part of it unless its important. Pertend everyone is your non-techie grandma. 

For people that are technocal and know what they are talking about flow digarams and stats always make people happy. And if you tested on a slow to med spec box and got great results do share. People are totally in to the "how will it scale"

Comment: Nice answer Moshe, +1. But what does POS stand for?

Comment: About Structuring your presentation: I think the contents has to have just as much a structure as the visual result. For this, think of 1 or 2 take away messages before writing down the presentation. A take away message is a main result/point that you want the audience to really understand and remember.

Comment: @user750378 - POS is "point of sale", edited.